# An implicit try {} catch around main

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

In each of my main functions, I would like to catch certain classes of exceptions and convert them to exit codes.

Is there a more elegant solution to this than starting and ending each main function with macros that will paste the implicit `try {} catch` I want?

Can I somehow achieve this with the `std::set_terminate` functionality?

Example:

```
int main(){
    try { //<- insert this

    /*
    the business logic goes here
    */

    //-> and insert this
    }
    catch(const Someclass1& e){ return 2; }
    catch(const Someclass2& e){ return 3; }
    //...
    catch(...){ return 1; } 
}
```

Comment: Are all your exceptions related by inheritance (or could they be?)

Comment: @quamrana Yes. It actually could be about just a single virtual base class.

Comment: You can then have each exception class embed the return code and a single try/catch in `main()` could extract it and return it.

Comment: My preferred approach avoids the macros:  http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2014/11/neater-way-handling-common-exceptions/

Comment: @Max Lybbert +1 Very nice. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxLybbert your is the finest solution I've seen so far. It deserves an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [clean way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/01/16/exception-boundaries.aspx) involves using a translation function with all of your exception boilerplate that returns the exit values for the corresponding exception.

```
template <typename Callable>
int call_and_translate_for_boundary(Callable&& func)
try {
    func();
    return 0;
}
catch(const Someclass1& e){ return 2; }
catch(const Someclass2& e){ return 3; }
//...
catch(...){ return 1; }
```

In your own code, you only concern yourself with wrapping your business logic with a lambda and passed that into the translation function so it can capture and translate for you.

```
int main() {
    return call_and_translate_for_boundary([&]{
        //business logic here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you *could* do something with macros if you want to. Here's how:

```
#define MY_MAIN int main(int argc, char** argv) try // <- yes, try here
#define MY_CATCH catch (const Someclass1& e){ return 1; } \
                 catch (const Someclass2& e){ return 1; } \
                 ... \
                 catch (...) { return -1; }

MY_MAIN
{
    // usual business...
    return 0;
}
MY_CATCH
```

The idea is to let the macro write a try catch "around" the main function body, which is all legal.

```
int main() try { throw 1; } catch (int i) { return 0; }
```

[little example live](http://ideone.com/my9QHW)

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this:

```
int main2();

int main() try {
    return main2();
} catch(std::exception &e)
{ 
    // some display...
}
```

You can have more catch handlers of course.

---

If you need to put the same list of catch handlers in multiple entry points,  that would be a different question. The solution there is to have `catch(...) { foo(); }`, where the `foo()` function does `try { throw; }` followed by all the catch handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt so. By the time terminate is called, you've already lost all exception information (to be more precise, you never had it - terminate is called when no handlers are available and than determination is made at the call site). Exception object is not even created when there is no approriate handler for this.

Answer (score 0):

The [cleanest solution](http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2014/11/neater-way-handling-common-exceptions/) I'm familiar with looks like:

```
void standard_exception_handler();

try {
    whatever();
}
catch (...)
{
    standard_exception_handler();
}

void standard_exception_handler()
{
    try {
        throw;  // a bare throw preserves the original exception information
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (const other_exception& ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

To have handlers outside of the common handler, you either need to have your common handler operate on a known type (e.g., change `catch (...)` to `catch (const my_exception& ex)`, and make required changes inside the common handler), or use nested `try` blocks:

```
try {
    try {
        whatever();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        standard_exception_handler();
    }
}
catch (const who_knows& ex)
{
    // log and exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may refine it still, but I figured out I can

- play rethrow-catch in the terminate handler 
   ([which is in fact what `std::terminate` does to print the
    `what():` line for `std::exception`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255368/how-does-stdterminate-know-to-treat-stdexceptions-specially/34256060))
- set the terminate handler from outside, so that `main` doesn't know about it at all

With this, my `main`s don't have to "know" about this exception-to-exitcode translation, which was my goal:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Someclass1 {};
struct Someclass2 {};

bool hasDefaultExceptionHandler = (std::set_terminate([](){
    try { throw; }
    catch(const Someclass1& e){ exit(2); }
    catch(const Someclass2& e){ exit(3); }
    catch(...){ exit(1); } 
}), true);

// Main has no idea
int main(){
  throw Someclass2{};
} //will exit with 3
```

---

Thanks to everybody for the good ideas.