# How does `std::terminate` know to treat `std::exception`s specially?

Tags: c++

This

```
#include <stdexcept>
struct A /*: public std::exception*/ {
  const char* what() const noexcept { return "this is A";  } 
};
int main(){
  throw A{};
  return 0;
}
```

gives me (on `stderr`):

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'A'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I uncomment the comment, the death message becomes:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'A'
what():  this is A
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How does `std::terminate` know to treat `std::exception`s specially?

How can I emulate this in my own `set_terminate`? I've tried

```
//...
int main(){
  std::set_terminate([](){
      printf("exception thrown\n");
      std::exception_ptr eptr = std::current_exception();
      std::exception* ptr =  dynamic_cast<std::exception*>(eptr);
      if (ptr) 
        puts(ptr->what());
  });
  throw A{};
}
```

but it won't compile because of the `dynamic_cast` line.

Comment: Apparently it [uses RTTI under the hood](https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/c-exceptions-under-the-hood-appendix-iii-rtti-and-exceptions-orthogonality/).

Comment: @user4815162342 Interestingly, I get that `what():` line even if I compile with `-fno-rtti`.

Comment: @PSkocik In linked article it is stated that parts of RTTI, nessesary to make exceptions work are used even with RTTI disabled. Usually stuff like that is done using compiler magic: builtins and compiler-specific code. `std::terminate` is implemented deep inside runtime library. libstdc++ just throws current exception and tries to catch `std::exception`. Source code: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/52744421/#l-47

Comment: @PSkocik Yes, the linked article addresses that point explicitly. According to the author's findings, `-fno-rtti` only disables the frontend functions like `typeid`, but the meachanism that implements RTTI is still used for exceptions behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely because it simply tries to `dynamic_cast` it to a `std::exception`, and invokes the virtual `what()` method, if the dynamic cast succeeds.

Comment: Turns out it can't attempt to `dynamic_cast` it to a `std::exception` because `dynamic_cast` only appears to work if the objects are in the same hierarchy. It doesn't even compile if they aren't.

Comment: @PSkocik : `dynamic_cast`ing the `exception_ptr` makes no sense, as it's an opaque type rather than a literal pointer.

Answer (score 4):

What `std::terminate` does can be approximately emulated with:

```
std::set_terminate([](){
  puts("exception thrown"); 
  //^skip the demangling of the typeid that's normaly done
  try { throw; } 
    catch(const std::exception& e){ puts(e.what()); }
    catch(...){}
  //^rethrow and catch
});
```

---

Thanks to [revolver-ocelot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410396/revolver-ocelot) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Note that you can replace `std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception()` with just `throw`. Although it looks out of place outside a `catch`, it works even on C++98.

Comment: You beat me to the punch by 3 or 4 seconds. :) The previous version was still interesting because I learned of `std::rethrow_exception` and `std::current_exception`, both new in C++11.

Comment: @user4815162342 Did that just a couple of seconds before your comment.

Comment: You also probably want a `catch(...)` -- otherwise throwing something that doesn't subclass `std::exception` will likely cause a loop calling the terminate handler.

Comment: @ChrisDodd It doesn't recurse, though. It behaves as if the terminate handler was `noexcept` -- if an exception is thrown from it, it dies. I don't know if this is guaranteed behavior but I figure it must be since this code basically copies gcc source code (except that this code does `throw;` instead of `__throw_exception_again;`).

Comment: @ChrisDodd I'll add it, though. Better safe than sorry. Thanks.

Comment: Throwing an exception from something declared `noexcept` calls `std:unexpected()` which by default just calls `std::terminate()`...